# ImportError: No module named genmsg.template_tools

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Kubuntu 12.04, Kernel 3.2.0-40-generic, installed ROS Groovy ros_comm version 1.9.44.
I've tried several times to install Groovy into a VMware Image and on a pure machine.
Trying to start the catkin build in Eclipse Juno (started from a bash window), i've got:

/usr/bin/make all
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/martin/catkin_ws/src -B/home/martin/catkin_ws/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/martin/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles /home/martin/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/martin/catkin_ws/build'
/usr/bin/make -f chatter_msgs/CMakeFiles/chatter_msgs_gencpp.dir/build.make chatter_msgs/CMakeFiles/chatter_msgs_gencpp.dir/depend
make[2]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/martin/catkin_ws/build'
cd /home/martin/catkin_ws/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/martin/catkin_ws/src /home/martin/catkin_ws/src/chatter_msgs /home/martin/catkin_ws/build /home/martin/catkin_ws/build/chatter_msgs /home/martin/catkin_ws/build/chatter_msgs/CMakeFiles/chatter_msgs_gencpp.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/martin/catkin_ws/build'
/usr/bin/make -f chatter_msgs/CMakeFiles/chatter_msgs_gencpp.dir/build.make chatter_msgs/CMakeFiles/chatter_msgs_gencpp.dir/build
make[2]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/martin/catkin_ws/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/martin/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles 1
[ 14%] Generating C++ code from chatter_msgs/Chatter.msg
cd /home/martin/catkin_ws/build/chatter_msgs && ../catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python /opt/ros/groovy/lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py /home/martin/catkin_ws/src/chatter_msgs/msg/Chatter.msg -Ichatter_msgs:/home/martin/catkin_ws/src/chatter_msgs/msg -Istd_msgs:/opt/ros/groovy/share/std_msgs/msg -p chatter_msgs -o /home/martin/catkin_ws/devel/include/chatter_msgs -e /opt/ros/groovy/share/gencpp
Traceback (most recent call last):
make[2]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/martin/catkin_ws/build'
**File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in 
import genmsg.template_tools
ImportError: No module named genmsg.template_tools**
make[2]: *** [/home/martin/catkin_ws/devel/include/chatter_msgs/Chatter.h] Fehler 1
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/martin/catkin_ws/build'
make[1]: *** [chatter_msgs/CMakeFiles/chatter_msgs_gencpp.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2

Does anybody know why? (I never programmed python)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60095/importerror:-no-module-named-genmsg.template_tools/) by [MartinHummel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4385/martinhummel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2013-04-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you need to add the PYTHONPATH variable to eclipse.
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Environment

The value should be /opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.
Can use "export | grep PYTHONPATH" to check your value.

---

Originally posted by [Jun Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/11061/jun-su/) with karma: 56 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eliasm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6851/eliasm/) on 2014-11-26**:
Worked for me as well on Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo, thanks!